# WooCommerce cannot access cart from product class

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce, cart

I have a custom WooComerce product type, and I need to access the cart url from within it.

Would seem simple enough:

```
class WC_Product_My_Product extends WC_Product_Simple {

 public function some_method() {
  global $woocommerce; 
  $href = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();     
 }
}
```

However:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function get_cart_url() on a non-object
```

What can possibily be wrong?

Is the `$woocommerce` variable not available when defining a custom product class?

If so, is there some internal method / variable to access it? (Or the cart specifically?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Updated for WC 3+*

Using `$woocommerce->cart = new WC_Cart();` to create a new object  instance is an apparently the solution to avoid error:

```
class WC_Product_My_Product extends WC_Product_Simple {

    public function some_method() {
        WC()->cart = new WC_Cart();
        $href = WC()->cart->get_cart_url();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this didn't work either, but I added some more code to provide better context. I am calling that in a method within the custom product type class

Comment: @DavidTonarini Can you edit your question with the full solution if possible so if others stumble upon this they will know what you did? Thanks!

Comment: @Shawn Sure, I could, but the accepted answer already has all the code. I think it is standard practice to leave the question as it is, in such case, as the answer already has the code? If not so, I will edit the question

Comment: Ok. When I read your comment below the solution it made me think there was more code you had to add to get it working.